# Debian - Atheroes AR9271 not working

Tags: debian, wifi, raspberry-pi, firmware

I'm trying to get AR9271 chipset to work under debian (Raspbian).

```
sudo lsusb | grep Atheros
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0cf3:9271 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR9271 802.11n
```

I have installed `firmware-atheros`.

```
lsmod | grep ath
ath9k_htc              56078  0 
ath9k_common           21766  1 ath9k_htc
ath9k_hw              415436  2 ath9k_common,ath9k_htc
ath                    18741  3 ath9k_common,ath9k_htc,ath9k_hw
mac80211              532034  1 ath9k_htc
cfg80211              427855  4 ath,ath9k_common,mac80211,ath9k_htc
```

iwconfig

```
iwconfig wlan0
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
```

But it seems like the AR9271 uses ath9k driver instead of ath9k_htc?

```
airmon-ng start wlan0
Interface   Chipset     Driver

wlan0       Atheros AR9271  ath9k - [phy1]
            (monitor mode enabled on mon0)
```

The problem comes when I try to change channel or something else.

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 channel 1
Error for wireless request "Set Frequency" (8B04) :
    SET failed on device wlan0 ; Device or resource busy.
```

If i try to start airodump-ng I get: `fixed channel mon0: -1`

My system:

```
uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.4.13-v7+ #894 SMP Mon Jun 13 13:13:27 BST 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

I guess this is a firmware problem?